# Create a node programmatically?

Tags: nodes

I found this code to create a node programmatically. It creates the node but the "title" field is not populated.

```
    $body_text = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.';

  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->type = 'flats';
  node_object_prepare($node);

  $node->title    = 'Node Created on ' . date('c');
  $node->language = 'en';

  $node->body[$node->language][0]['value']   = $body_text;
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = text_summary($body_text);
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['format']  = 'filtered_html';

  $path = 'content/my-lipsum-' . date('YmdHis');
  $node->path = array('alias' => $path);

  node_save($node);
```

The machine name of my Title is "title_field", but using this neither works:

```
  $node->title_field    = 'Node Created on ' . date('c');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using https://www.drupal.org/project/title ? If that's the case you must treat it like a field:

```
$node->title_field[$node->language][0]['value'] = 'Node Created on ' . date('c');
```

Comment: Yes I am, but still not working. The node is created and I can see the the title in '/admin/content' but once I edit the node the Title field is empy, same happens with the 'body' field, both are empty.

Comment: If I use this line it works: $node->title_field['und'][0]['value']    = 'Node Created Programmatically on ';